# Active Diretory domain name same as site

Tags: dns

The domain name of an active directory forest is, for example,

example.com

It is possible to access the site

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (no relation to active directory domain)

from a computer in that domain?
If so, what changes must be made to the domain's DNS server to make this possible?